# Por qué debo actualizar la página para poder obtener los datos del localStorage si ya habían sido guardados

Tags: javascript

Estoy guardando unos datos en el localStorage pero debo actualizar la página para poder obtenerlos y no entiendo por qué si ya estaban guardados.

```js
let storge = localStorage.getItem("message");

function store() {

if (storge != null) {

document.write(storge);

} else {

localStorage.setItem("message", "hola");

store();

}

}

store();
```

Comment: Ese código, al ejecutarlo tal cual, devuelve en consola _too much recursion_. ¿Por qué hacés que la función se llame a sí misma? Por cierto, los snippets no funcionan para _localStorage_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage guarda variables primitivas, esto quiere decir que lo que obtienes desde localStorage.getItem es en este caso un string, por lo que al guardar el valor en localStorage si lo quieres ver reflejado en tu variable "storge" tienes que volver a leerlo

```js
let storge = localStorage.getItem('message');

function store() {
  if (storge != null) {
    console.log(storge);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('message', 'hola');
    storge = localStorage.getItem('message');
    store();
  }
}

store();
```